# kitchen.yml attributes not override default values - Chef 12.12 - Kitchen 1.10

Tags: chef-infra, test-kitchen, chefdk, chef-zero

I have a simple attributes file: `attributes/default.rb`.

```
default['simpleattr'] = 'file value'
```

And inside `kitchen.yml`, I do

```
suites:
  - name: default
    run_list: 
      - recipe[simple::default]
    attributes:
     simpleattr: 'value from kitchen'
     simple:
       simpleattr: 'value from kitchen'
```

Inside the recipe, I do :

```
log  "default['simpleattr']: "+node.default['simpleattr']
```

And I always get `'file value'` rather than `'value from kitchen'` as output.

I want to override the value in tests.

Comment: To access the value that you define in test-kitchen, you would need to access `node['simple']['simpleattr']`. Don't access attributes via `node.default`, but `node['simpleattr'] instead. In the YAML, the lines below `attributes` line lack one space indentation. You can verify that the YAML is parsed correctly via `kitchen diagnose`.

Comment: I hope I got the root of the problem (see my answer)

Comment: You were happily ignoring everything that I wrote in my comment..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't access node values through `node.default[]`, but use `node[]` instead. Chef's [attribute hierarchy](https://docs.chef.io/attributes.html) automatically calculates the values according to its precedence levels.

I've reproduced your issue and uploaded it [here on Github](https://github.com/StephenKing/stackoverflow-38833508). The [solution](https://github.com/StephenKing/stackoverflow-38833508/commit/d0f52566aba9c3ab62ad9862df62477d392c676d) is as also previously described in my comment. Don't use

```
node.default['simpleattr']
```

but instead

```
node['simpleattr']
```

Then everything is as you expect and the output is

```
Recipe: simple::default
  * log[default['simpleattr']: value from kitchen] action write
```